# unable to load dll 'olepro32.dll' the specified module could not be found

Tags: windows, dll

When running a custom windows forms application, I get this error, `unable to load dll 'olepro32.dll' the specified module could not be found`.  From some searching, this seems to be a Windows system file.  Could this file really become corrupted or get installed with a bad version?  If so, how do I fix it?  I'm aware that I **should not download a dll from some random site**, but instead **get it from Microsoft**.

### EDIT

Seems like it might be a problem with Ink?  The custom windows app I'm talking about does use Ink.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c66cf0e8-c70e-47f7-91ba-fb114d93c055/ink-desktop-20-not-working-in-vista?forum=tabletandtouch

*Quite honestly the reason I am asking this question here is because I did not see any stack exchange sites listed in the top 20 Google search.  I trust stack exchange, and other sites... not so much.*

Comment: Welcome to DLL hell.  You might be experiencing a problem where the specific version of `olepro32.dll` is not loaded onto your system.  Is this some software that you wrote?  Or do you know the developers?  You may need to ensure their setup package contains the correct `olepro32.dll` the application was compiled with.

Comment: run **sfc /scannow** to repair corrupted/missing files

Comment: Thank you for the comment about **sfc**.  We will give that a try and report back.

Comment: was sfc able to fix it?

Comment: We are still working on the fix.  I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Thanks for your help @magicandre1981.  Much appreciated.  See my answer for the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved it.  The problem was with a very old version of **`Microsoft.Ink.dll`**.

The developers included a new dll in the package with version `6.1` instead of `1.7`.

*The `olepro32.dll` did not seem to be the problem after all.  All users had the dll in their `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder.  `sfc` did not turn up anything.*